# Task environment with answer key

Tags: hyperref, tasks, answers

I fixed my problem using hyperref, posted by CarLaTeX Visit [Task environment and answer package clash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406341/task-environment-and-answer-package-clash?rq=1). I got what I want and how to let the answer key be in the horizontal direction, not in vertical.

This is the question part
[image: This is the question part]

The answer key part

[image: The answer key part]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=10mm,
 right=10mm,
 top=15mm,
 }


\newcommand{\mybox}[4][\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-2mm]{%
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[line width=.5mm, rounded corners, draw=#2, inner ysep=10pt, text width=#1, outer sep=0] (one) {\vspace*{15pt}\\\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}#4\end{varwidth}};
\node[text=white,anchor=north east,align=center, minimum height=20pt] (two) at (one.north east) {#3 \hspace*{.5mm}};
\path[fill=#2] 
    (one.north west|-two.west) --
    ($(two.west)+(-1.5cm,0)$) 
    to[out=0,in=180] (two.south west) --
    (two.south east) [rounded corners] --
    (one.north east) -- 
    (one.north west) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
\node[text=white,anchor=north east,align=center, minimum height=20pt, text height=2ex] (three) at (one.north east) {#3 \hspace*{.5mm}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%          NEW            %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black}
\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseListHeader}{\textbf{\color{black}\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel}.}~}
\renewcommand{\AnswerListHeader}{\textbf{\color{black}\ExerciseHeaderNB.}~}
\newcommand{\itemi}{\Exercise[label={\the\value{Exercise}}]\setlength{\parskip}{1em}}
\newcommand{\myansw}{\Answer[ref=\ExerciseLabel]}









\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\mybox{gray!70!black}{\Large{Test 1}}{
\hspace*{7.5cm}
Topic 1: linear equations
}
\end{center}
  \begin{multicols*}{2}
    \begin{ExerciseList}
 %%%%%1%%%%%%%
       \itemi If the ratio of two 
\begin{tasks}[counter-format = {(tsk[A])},label-offset = {0.8em},item-indent={-0.1cm},label-format = {\bfseries}](5)
\task $36^\circ$
\task $44^\circ$
\task $48^\circ$
\task $52^\circ$
\task $60^\circ$
\end{tasks}
        \myansw C
        
        
%%%%%%%%%%%%%Q2%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\itemi If the angle
\begin{tasks}[counter-format = {(tsk[A])},label-offset = {0.8em},item-indent={-0.1cm},label-format = {\bfseries}](5)
\task $130^\circ$
\task $125^\circ$
\task $120^\circ$
\task $115^\circ$
\task $110^\circ$
\end{tasks}
 \myansw E



%%%%%%%%%%%%%Q3%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\itemi 1+1=?
\begin{tasks}[counter-format = {(tsk[A])},label-offset = {0.8em},item-indent={-0.1cm},label-format = {\bfseries}](5)
\task 50
\task 60
\task 70
\task 80
\task 90
\end{tasks}
 \myansw C          
    \end{ExerciseList}  
 \end{multicols*}
 
 
    \clearpage
    \section*{Answers!}\vspace{-1em}
    \shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes, my problem solved,

Comment: first, if you like this test paper, you can make several  test papers , when you use \newpapge, the counter will not start from 0, so you need to add  \setcounter{Exercise}{0} just before, \begin{ExerciseList},    for the answer key , Im using \textlabel{D-1}{D}    \ref{D-1}, you can change the D-1 to anything you want, I created a colored table and input \ref{} into the table, it pretty good, when you used for next paper you can use ctrl+R to replace D-1 to E-1 and also change \ref{D-1}to \ref{E-1} too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by OP himself. Also this question looks like an answer, not a question.